# How would I create a Python module?

Tags: python

I have a Math and Physics program that I want to make. I have decided that instead of putting all of it in one file I should separate it into several files. I later learnt that the act of doing this is creating a module. I have looked around the web and all the tutorials there are very confusing. I would like to know how to create a module and all of the basic technical details behind it. I am also confused by the term python path. When I looked up a tutorial on creating modules it looked like this:

```
# Fibonacci numbers module

def fib(n):    # write Fibonacci series up to n
    a, b = 0, 1
    while b < n:
        print b,
        a, b = b, a+b

def fib2(n): # return Fibonacci series up to n
    result = []
    a, b = 0, 1
    while b < n:
        result.append(b)
        a, b = b, a+b
    return result

import fibo
```

Comment: You are confusing *module* with **package**. A python *module* is a single '.py' file. A **package** is a collection of *modules* that are logically grouped together. I think you should probably re-read the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html) on them, it will help clear them up.

Comment: You'll also want to take a look at `__init__.py` files for packages: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for

Answer (score 1):

From the [Python documentation about Modules](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#modules):

> A module is a file containing Python definitions and statements. The
>   file name is the module name with the suffix `.py` appended.

To create a Module with this two functions, you have to move your function `fib` and `fib2` to a file called `fibo.py`.

Then you have to create a second script to use this new module with `import fibo`:

```
import fibo

fibo.fib(1000)
```

Make sure Python can find the Module. From the [Python documentation about The Module Search Path](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path):

> When a module named spam is imported, the interpreter first searches
>   for a built-in module with that name. If not found, it then searches
>   for a file named spam.py in a list of directories given by the
>   variable `sys.path`. `sys.path` is initialized from these locations:
>
> - the directory containing the input script (or the current directory).
> - `PYTHONPATH` (a list of directory names, with the same syntax as the shell variable `PATH`).
> - the installation-dependent default.
>
> After initialization, Python programs can modify `sys.path`. The
>   directory containing the script being run is placed at the beginning
>   of the search path, ahead of the standard library path. This means
>   that scripts in that directory will be loaded instead of modules of
>   the same name in the library directory. This is an error unless the
>   replacement is intended.

If you are interested in Modules, you probably will be interested in Packages too. From the [Python documentation about Packages](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages):

> Packages are a way of structuring Python’s module namespace by using
>   “dotted module names”. For example, the module name `A.B` designates a
>   submodule named `B` in a package named `A`. Just like the use of modules
>   saves the authors of different modules from having to worry about each
>   other’s global variable names, the use of dotted module names saves
>   the authors of multi-module packages like NumPy or the Python Imaging
>   Library from having to worry about each other’s module names.

This is how to create a Package:

> When importing the package, Python searches through the directories on
>   `sys.path` looking for the package subdirectory.
>
> The `__init__.py` files are required to make Python treat the
>   directories as containing packages; this is done to prevent
>   directories with a common name, such as string, from unintentionally
>   hiding valid modules that occur later on the module search path. In
>   the simplest case, `__init__.py` can just be an empty file, but it can
>   also execute initialization code for the package or set the `__all__`
>   variable, described later.

Answer (score 0):

Put this:

```
def fib(n):    # write Fibonacci series up to n
    a, b = 0, 1
    while b < n:
        print b,
        a, b = b, a+b

def fib2(n): # return Fibonacci series up to n
    result = []
    a, b = 0, 1
    while b < n:
        result.append(b)
        a, b = b, a+b
    return result
```

in a file. If you want to use it only in the current directory,
leave it there. If you want to use it from everywhere, put it
in the site-packages directory of Python.

That's it...

You can add something like this at the end of the file:

```
def main():
    # Add test code for the library functions here
    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This makes it possible to 'execute' the library immediately,
running eg. test code for the routines which are in it. If
it's called as module (with import), then the `if` at the end
will **not** call `main()` and it's just a library.

It's as simple as that. The python path assure where Python
will look, which is normally in all site-packages dirs.